# Skype returning empty CHATMESSAGES results through the DBus API

Tags: skype, dbus

I am trying to use Skype's DBus API in order to retrieve the list of messages (message IDs) I've exchanged with a contact. However, both the `SEARCH CHATMESSAGES <target>` (protocol >= 3) and the `SEARCH MESSAGES <target>` (protocol < 3) commands return unexpectedly empty results.

Here is the trace of a few exchanges I had with the API. I used [d-feet](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/DFeet?action=show&redirect=DFeet) to send my requests, but the result is exactly the same when I send the request from my own program.

- Bus name: `com.Skype.API`
- Object: `/com/Skype`
- Interface: `com.Skype.API`
- Method used: `Invoke(String request)`

Trace:

```
-> NAME dfeet
<- OK
-> PROTOCOL 8
<- PROTOCOL 8
-> SEARCH CHATMESSAGES mycontact
<-
```

The same thing happens with two other `SEARCH` commands:

- `SEARCH MESSAGES <target>` (with `PROTOCOL 2`).
- `SEARCH CHATS`

Additionally, I also get an empty result when I try to request a message list based on a chat ID: `GET CHAT <chat_id> GETMESSAGES`.

However, commands such as `SEARCH FRIENDS`, `SEARCH CALLS`, or `SEARCH ACTIVECHATS` work just fine, and return their lists of IDs (contacts IDs, calls IDs, or chat IDs) as expected.

*It might also be worth noting that this happens for all contacts, regardless of how many messages I've exchanged with them (I thought at first that there might be too many messages involved, but the result is the same, whether I've sent 3, or thousands of messages to the contact).*

Is there anything that would explain why I get these empty responses through DBus, for these requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Skype will not use `Invoke`'s return value when its reply is too heavy.** As it so happens, when Skype has too much data to prepare and transfer after a request, it automatically returns an empty string to the `Invoke` call. The *true, heavy* reply is then prepared asynchrously by Skype, and the client program must be ready to receive it when it eventually arrives.

Whenever you are communicating with Skype over DBus, your application must act as both a client (calling `Invoke`), and a server (providing a DBus object for Skype to reach). This design was a little unexpected (I guess we could argue on its quality), but here is what it requires you to do:

1. Make your program a DBus "server" (providing objects to reach). Through your bus name to Skype, register an object path called `/com/Skype/Client` implementing the `com.Skype.API.Client` interface.
2. Prepare a message handler for the only method of this interface: `Notify(s)`. This is the method Skype will try to call to send you the heavy reply to one of your previous requests.
3. Program your own mechanism to match your `Invoke` request with the asynchronous `Notify` message coming in as an answer later on.

The creation of an object can be done through [`dbus_connection_register_object_path`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusConnection.html#ga24730ca6fd2e9132873962a32df7628c), the parameters for which are:

- The `DBusConnection` structure representing your bus name.
- The object path you are registering, here `/com/Skype/Client`.
- A table of message handlers (`DBusObjectPathVTable`) used to process all incoming requests.
- Data to be sent to these handlers when they are called. *This is additional data, not the actual message being received since you're just setting up the handler here.*

For instance...

```
DBusHandlerResult notify_handler(DBusConnection *connection, 
                                DBusMessage *message, 
                                void *user_data){
    return DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_HANDLED;
}

void unregister_handler(DBusConnection *connection, 
                        void *user_data){}

DBusObjectPathVTable vtable = {
    unregister_handler,
    message_handler,
    NULL
};

if(!dbus_connection_register_object_path(connection,
                                         "/com/Skype/Client",
                                         &vtable, NULL)){
    // Error...
}
```

Note that this is just an object's definition. In order to actually *hook* on the `Notify` calls, you'll have to `select()` on a `DBusWatch` file descriptor, and dispatch the incoming `DBusMessage` in order to have your message handler called.

If you are working with other bindings, you'll probably find much faster ways to setup objects and start working as a client application. See:

- [GLib's `g_dbus_connection_register_object`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusConnection.html#g-dbus-connection-register-object)
- [Exporting objects with `dbus-python`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html#exporting-objects)
- [QtDBus's `QDBusConnection::registerObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdbusconnection.html#registerObject)
- [... (other bindings)](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/)